# Complement maketrans in python for translate

Tags: python, perl, translate, tr

For translating `tr` in perl to python, I am using `string.maketrans` and `str.translate`.  However, for the perl expression:

```
$val =~ tr/\0-\377//c
```

The user is asking for the complement of the translation.  How I generate python code for that?

Comment: Better way to phrase the question: "How do I count the number of characters in a string that are outside the range 00..FF?"

Comment: That's just a sample input - the user can put anything there.  My program is called "pythonizer" and it translates perl to python. Plus I think this case REMOVES all characters not in 00..FF.

Comment: Re "*Plus I think this case REMOVES all characters not in 00..FF.*", It does not. /// Re "*That's just a sample input*", Providing a Python implementation of tr/// is outside the scope of SO.

Comment: Some people are giving me ideas on how to handle sub-cases of it, which I can match and generate - see below!

Comment: You specifically said you don't want to handle just this one case, and the answer doesn't even handle this one case correctly.

Comment: Interesting - well people like yourself are helping me understand the issue.  I just tested it and it doesn't even do what I think it would do.  Test case for upper-case letters:

    $ perl
    $val = "AbcDE";
    $c = $val =~ tr/\101-\132//c;
    print "$c, $val\n";
    2, AbcDE

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to delete characters not int the range of ordinal values [0-255], then you could simply do

```
val = "".join([ch for ch in val if 0o000 <= ord(ch)<= 0o377])
```

Comment: Re "*I assume you want to delete characters*", `tr/\0-\377//c` doesn't delete any characters.

Comment: @ikegami Yes I agree, I assumed they wanted to delete not count.

Comment: Odd assumption. But anyway, they clarified they are writing a translator and want to handle any tr///c (and probably any tr///) in Python.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami - I made that same wrong assumption looking at that perl code until I wrote a little test case (see my comment above).  It doesn't change $val, it just counts the chars that are not in range.

Comment: Ok this translation will work if the user also specifies the "d" flag.

Comment: @snoopyjc Yes. However, it is not completely clear to me what you want. Maybe you could update your question with more information. For example with expected output for some sample cases.

Comment: @HåkonHægland pythonizer is a general purpose translator from perl to python.  I'm trying to implement the 'c' flag on tr statements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I implemented in [perllib](https://pypi.org/project/perllib/):

```
def _maketrans_c(arg1, arg2, delete=False):
    """Make a complement tr table for the 'c' flag.  If the 'd' flag is passed, then delete=True.  Ranges are expanded in arg1 and arg2 but arg2 is not otherwise normalized"""
    t = str.maketrans(arg1, arg1)
    d = dict()
    for i in range(257):
        if i not in t:
            if not arg2:
                if delete:
                    d[i] = None
                else:
                    d[i] = i
            elif i < len(arg2):
                d[i] = arg2[i]
            elif delete:
                d[i] = None
            else:
                d[i] = arg2[-1]

    return str.maketrans(d)


def _translate_and_count(table, var, replace=True, complement=False, delete=False, squash=False):
    """Perform a tr translate, but also count the # of matches"""
    result = []
    ctr = 0;
    pv = None
    for ch in var:
        if ord(ch) > 256 and complement:
            ch = chr(256)
        try:
            v = table[ord(ch)]
            ctr += 1
        except LookupError:
            v = ch
            pv = None
        if v is not None:
            if isinstance(v, int):
                v = chr(v)
            if pv != v or not squash:
                result.append(v)
        pv = v
    if not replace:
        return (var, ''.join(result))
    return (''.join(result), ctr)
```